# Hat "Ananas" 2 oder 3 Silben?

Tags: hyphenation

Gibt es Silben, welche nur aus einem Silbenkern bestehen?

Meine Verwirrung kommt von einer Internet-Suche; diese brachte mich auf wohl automatische Silbenerkennungs-Seiten, oder irgendwelche Frageportale, auf welchen es zwei Meinungen gibt:

1. "Ananas" besteht aus 2 Silben.
2. "Ananas" besteht aus 3 Silben, wobei die erste Silbe nicht "An", sondern lediglich "A" ist, allerdings darf die erste Silbe nicht durch Silbentrennung abgetrennt werden.

An sich verstehe ich, dass es sinnvoll ist, "A" als Silbe zu sehen: Schließlich haben wir nur einen Silbenkern pro Silbe, welcher meistens ein Vokal ist. Vokal-Konsonant-Vokal(-Konsonant-Konsonant-...) ist doch ganz klar gegen die Bildungsregeln. Dennoch bin ich verunsichert von der Meinung, das Wort bestehe aus nur 2 Silben. Muss eine Silbe also nicht trennbar sein, um eine Silbe zu sein? Existieren untrennbare Silben?

Was ist also nun mit "Ananas", mit "aber", "über", und Ähnlichen?

Answer (score 9):

Es ist ziemlich irreführend, zu behaupten, dass *Ananas* aus zwei Silben bestünde, weil man *Ana-nas* trennt. Diese Trennung wird durch die Rechtschreibregeln festgelegt. Und dort heißt es im Abschnitt Worttrennung in der Fassung von 2016 (zwischendurch, z.B. nach den [Regeln von 2004](https://www.rechtschreibrat.com/DOX/rfdr_Regeln_2004.pdf), § 108, wäre auch *A-na-nas* möglich gewesen):

> [Amtliche Regeln, § 107](https://grammis.ids-mannheim.de/rechtschreibung/6214)
>
> E1: Einzelne Vokalbuchstaben am Wortanfang oder -ende werden nicht abgetrennt, auch nicht bei Komposita, zum Beispiel: *Abend, Kleie, Ju-li-abend, Bio-müll*

Die Sprechsilben sind *A-bend, Klei-e, Bi-o* und eben *A-na-nas* und nicht Gegenstand von Rechtschreibregeln, sondern Einheiten der Sprache. Dort kann selbstverständlich ein einzelner Vokal eine Silbe bilden. (Es gibt auch andere Abweichungen zwischen silbischer Struktur und Worttrennung; z.B. die Trennung *nati-onal* für *natio-nal*.)

<sup>Ursprünglich hatte ich behauptet, dass *Ana-nas* aus zwei Schreibsilben bestünde. Damit habe ich aber nur den Missbrauch des Silbenbegriffs, wie er vielleicht auf einigen Seiten im Internet zu finden ist, übernommen. Der wissenschaftliche Begriff der Schreibsilbe, so z.B. in der Duden-Grammatik, 8./9. Aufl., Randnr. 84., hat damit nichts zu tun.</sup>

Comment: Leider gibt es zu viele Webseiten, die da nicht differenzieren. Daher kam meine Verwirrung. Danke für die Aufklärung.

Comment: Kann es sein, dass das eine dieser Regeln war, die vor der Rechtschreibreform bestanden, dann verworfen wurden (und man eine Weile lang offiziell A-bend oder Klei-e schreiben durfte) und dann nach einiger Zeit wiederhergestellt wurden?

Comment: Das Irreführende ist mE, bei der "Silbentrennung" überhaupt von "Silben" zu sprechen. Wie auf der verlinkten Seite der amtlichen Regeln auch schön beschreiben ist, gilt: "Dabei stimmen die Grenzen der Silben, in die man die geschriebenen Wörter bei langsamem Vorlesen zerlegen kann, **gewöhnlich** mit den Trennstellen überein." (Hervorhebung von mir.) Die Trennung am Zeilenende ist also an die Silben *angelehnt*, aber mehr auch nicht. Umgekehrt ist es aussichtslos, anhand von Trennungsregeln irgendeine Aussage zu den gesprochenen Silben eines Wortes belegen zu wollen (insbesondere, wenn ...

Comment: ... diese im Widerspruch zur Aussprache zu stehen scheinen).

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Ich stimme dem größtenteils zu. Ich dachte, mithilfe des Begriffs der Schreibsilbe ein Missverständnis aufklären zu können, habe es aber damit nur perpetuiert.

Answer (score 0):

Ja, es gibt Silben, die nur aus einem Silbenkern bestehen. Jede Silbe hat einen Silbenkern. Die Silbenrändern hingegen – Silbenanlaut und -auslaut – können (je nach Sprache) leer sein. Das Wort *Ananas* hat also drei Silben.

Das Deutsche gehört zu den Sprachen, wo sowohl Silbenan- als auch -auslaut leer sein können. In einem Wort wie *tue* besteht die zweite Silbe aus nichts weiter als einem Silbenkern ohne An- oder Auslaut. Ähnlich verhält es sich bei der ersten Silbe von einem Wort wie *Oase* in denjenigen Varietäten des Deutschen, wo einem Vokal am Wortanfang kein Glottisschlag vorangesetzt wird, also etwa im Schweizer Hochdeutsch.

Answer (score -1):

Früher hat man uns eingebläut, dass einzelne Vokale nicht abtrennbar sind. Das ist aber eine optische Regel, denn es gibt im Deutschen keine Silben, die mit einem Vokal beginnen.

*Wie? Was?*

„Beginnt“ eine Silbe mit einem Vokal, knallen wir doch noch den Knacklaut davor! Das ist ein Konsonant, er wird halt bloß nicht geschrieben.

Ananas ist also ein dreisilbiges Wort.

Comment: [ˈananas] [ˈaːbɐ] [ˈyːbɐ]
Ich nehme an, mit dem Knacklaut ist ˈ gemeint? Danke für die Antwort. Bedeutet: Schriftlich kann man nur 2 Silben sehen, Lautlich aber 3 Silben hören? Bzw lautlich in 3 auftrennen, schriftlich aber nur in 2 auftrennen?

Comment: Nein, dieses ˈ markiert in der IPA-Schreibweise die Hauptbetonung eines Wortes. Der Knacklaut wird ʔ geschrieben, aber z.B. im Wiktionary benutzen sie den nicht. Und ja, richtig. Es sind lautlich drei Silben. Und schriftlich kann man das halt nicht darstellen, weil wir den Knacklaut nicht schreiben, und irgendwann mal entschieden wurde, dass einzelne Vokale nicht abgetrennt werden sollen, weil das im Schriftsatz blöd aussieht.

Comment: Das ist überraschend. Würdest du aus dem Stehgreif eventuell eine Quelle wissen, bei der ich mehr darüber erfahren kann?

Comment: Was denn genau?

Comment: Selbstverständlich gibt es im Deutschen Silben, die mit einem Vokal beginnen. Einerseits ist in der Schweiz der Glottisschlag nicht üblich – schon alleine damit ist die Aussage widerlegt. Darüber hinaus ist in Wörtern wie _real, Theater_ auch ausserhalb der Schweiz der Glottisschlag nicht üblich. Und darüber hinaus haben Wörtern wie _böig, säe, tue, ruhig_ nicht einmal im allerpreussischsten Norddeutsch einen Glottisschlag.

Comment: Dann trenne mal bitte *böig*, ohne einen Knacklaut zu machen. Es geht nicht. Entweder du sprichst es als eine Silbe mit einem Gleitlaut oder du knackst.

Comment: Du irrst dich. Das Wort _böig_ hat zwei Silben, aber keinen Glottisschlag, vgl. [böig – Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/b%C3%B6ig) oder andere Aussprachewörterbücher. Wenn jemand Norddeutsches das Wort getrennt spricht, dann würden sie wohl einen Glottisschlag produzieren. Eine getrennte Aussprache ist aber künstlich und entspricht eher dem gesprochenen Buchstabieren als der gewöhnlichen Aussprache des Worts.

Comment: Genau darauf wollte ich aber hinaus. Der Knacklaut ist eine reine Ausspracheregel. Die Verwirrung des Fragestellers rührt vermutlich auch daher, zu erwarten, dass die Silben lexikalisch wären. Das sind sie aber nicht, wie man ganz ohne Knacklaut allein an Wörtern mit oder ohne Endungen erkennt, z.B. der Laut, des Lau|tes.

Comment: *Beeilen* ist leider ein Gegenbeispiel.